# How to prevent a Bluetooth keyboard from auto-sleeping on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I use a Bluetooth keyboard that can connect to multiple devices and it is pretty decent, but its auto-sleep (power saving) function drives me crazy, especially when I'm on a call and stop typing for a few minutes, then when I have to type in a question or answer, the first characters get lost (I can't win any group quizzes unless I keep pressing keys on my keyboard to keep it awake :-P).

It is very annoying having to press a few keys and wait a few seconds before I start typing, whenever I stay 5 minutes without touching any key (eg. reading, calls, etc.).

<s>On Windows, we have a setting to prevent a Bluetooth device from entering sleep mode, but I couldn't find anything similar for macOS.</s> *

Is there a way to prevent such devices from sleeping (entering standby mode) on a Mac?

Currently on an Intel-based Macbook Pro, running Ventura 13.2.1, using a JOYACCESS JA-KB07 low-profile Bluetooth keyboard.

**Edit:** I contacted the JoyAccess support and they weren't helpful. It seems there are issues to understand the issue and questions in English and I don't speak Chinese to properly communicate with them.
They just gave me some unrelated model manual with instructions on how to pair the keyboard with a computer and mouse.

<sup>* The Windows setting prevents the computer from turning off the device to save power but doesn't prevent the device itself from entering power-saving mode.</sup>

Comment: Disable sleep mode on the keyboard.

Comment: What *Windows* setting disables a BT device from sleeping?

Comment: @Allan, there is a "allow computer to turn off device to save power" option in the "Power Management" tab, in "Properties" for those devices in "Device Manager".

Comment: @MarcWilson, My keyboard doesn't have any setting for that, nor MacOS provides any that I'm aware of. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @RicardoSouza That Windows option does not do what you think it does.  What keyboard?

Comment: Oh yep, you are right. It must be a keyboard specific thing then.
I'm on a cheap Joyaccess JA-KB07, which is a low profile bluetooth keyboard that supports up to 3 devices.

Comment: My Logitech MX Keys goes to sleep on a Mac after a few seconds and loses the first 2 keystrokes before working again.

Comment: If your Mac goes to sleep so will the BT

Comment: @Ruskes, my issue is that the keyboard enters power saving mode every 5 minutes without a key press while I'm watching videos or I'm on a video call. The laptop is still active and that even happens if I'm only using the mouse without touching the keyboard.

Comment: I am afraid that is a OEM firmware that you can not change. However you could write a script to send BT signal to the BT keyboard to keep it alive.

Comment: Maybe this would help https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349473/46541

Comment: Thanks Ruskes, but my problem is really on the keyboard itself. It comes with that power saving as a factory configuration and I don't know if it is even possible to change it, as it didn't came with a manual and asking the manufacturer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the manufacturer of your Bluetooth keyboard provides any software or firmware updates that might include power management settings.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342506)

Comment: It would be a good idea to [edit] and remove the question from your answer as it is confusing. Besides, the OP has stated, in the question, that the model is `JOYACCESS JA-KB07`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this seems more suitable for a comment and, as Greenonline pointed out, I've stated the model in my question.
I also contacted the manufacturer, but their support is not great at answering questions in English. I'll update the question with that information.